# Use ld-linux.so.2 from org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386 without Flatpak infrastructure

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, wine, flatpak, fedora-silverblue

I want to use Valve Proton without Steam on immutable Fedora Silverblue distro, but I can't install compat i386 libs system wide (I don't want to layer packages etc). I think that I may use libs from org.freedesktop.Platform and org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386 with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, however I don't know how to choose ld-linux.so.2 from org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386 package. Flatpak somehow set this libs as "active" but I can't find anywhere how this process works. At now when I try to start app via Proton I just see:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: could not open
```

Can you help me?